# Facebook API metods returns null

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am testing out Facebook API with Java. However i am getting null in return when i call the get metodes. I did make sure to grant all access to my graph token such as(User.status, location, friends etc) to my  FB account on the api website. Connection and permission seem to be working fine, as i dont get any other errors. Are there permissions I`m missing ?

Why am i getting null in return ? Below is my code.

```
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(ApiKey,Version.VERSION_6_0);
        User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
        System.out.println(user.getFirstName());      // returns null in the console
```

Comment: Is there any property which isn't null in the user? Perhaps this is just a missing field

Comment: No, unfortunately all properties return null :/

Comment: Might be due to the fact that you are not explicitly asking for any fields, so you will only get the id and name fields back by default.

Comment: @CBroe how do you suggest i ask in a more explicit manner?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fields - but don’t ask me how that translates into the syntax of the library you are using there, dunno.